# geocode return REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

google.maps.Geocoder().geocode always return REQUEST_DENIED with all the APIs enabled in a commercial google map account

We tried to use a key of a paid commercial account with all the APIs (15 of them) enabled but still got REQUEST_DENIED when calling google.maps.Geocoder().geocode

```
    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode( { 'address': site.address}, function(results, status) {
    //console.log('address:'+ site.address)
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        site.latitude = latitude
        site.longitude = longitude
        if (callback) {
            callback(site)
        }
      } else {
          if (errorHandler) {
              errorHandler.call(self, "Invalide address")
          }
      } 
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The REQUEST_DENIED error status code usually means there is an issue with your project setup or api key. Besides [enabling billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#create-billing-account), to use Google's Geocoder:

1. You need to use an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#get-the-api-key).
2. The Geocoding API and the Javascript API must be [enabled](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#enable-api-sdk).
3. The API key must be properly [restricted](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key).

Hope this helps you and anyone else who encounters this error.

Answer (score 0):

After setting API restrict, it still returns `REQUEST_DENIED`.

Then, I restart the [bill account](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/home/dashboard), and it works.